# What's the point of a patent?

Tags: patent-infringement

I go to the store and I see many knock offs of name brand items that look and taste just like the original. Sometimes even the box look a like. This also goes for toys, phones, cars etc. Whats the point of having a patent if someone can change a small ( really small ) feature and say its new? I'm suppose to spend thousands of dollars and can still get people bring my idea to market!

I kind of feel that here in the u.s the monopoly laws kinds of go against the patent theory. If I make a brand new product and get a patent so no one can steal it then I'm in a sense a monopoly. But if people can still take my idea then patents are useless.. I'm sure there's a reason but what is it?

Comment: It's unclear if you ware talking about design patent (ornamental features) or utility patent (function/mechanism). Please clarify.

Comment: All patents I see it done with many different pieces if work and creations

Comment: That's correct. Innovation rarely take quantum leap. Most innovation are derivative of others' (or inventor's own) work.

Comment: What type of product are you working on?  This may be relevant because patent eligible subject matter is an ever changing thing.